# Mapping lazy relationship with DAO Factory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mapping, dao

What I'm trying to do is to make a lazy relationship between a Bean attributes and a DAO.

So here is my code:

Bean Article

```
public class Article {
    private Long id;
    private Product product;
    private Attribut attribut;
    private String name;
    private Article ParentArticle;
    \\ getters and setters
}
```

DAO for mapping the article to a Bean

```
private Article map(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        Article article = new Article();
        \\set the id of the Article
        article.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));     
        \\get the DAO of each article Bean attribute
        ProductDao productDao = daoFactory.getProductDao();
        ArticleDao articleDao = daoFactory.getArticleDao();
        AttributsDao attributsDao = daoFactory.getAttributDao();`

        \\set the product of the article by searching the product with his DAO
        article.setProduct(productDao.find(resultSet.getLong("idProduct")));

        \\set the Attribut of the article by searching the attribute with his DAO   
        article.setAttribut(attributsFonctionsDao.trouver(resultSet.getLong("idAttribut")));
       \\set the designation of the article     article.setDesignation(resultSet.getString("designationArticle"));
        \\set the Parent Article by searching the article with his DAO 
        article.setParentArticle(articleDao.trouver(resultSet.getLong("idArticleParent")));
        return article;
    }
```

So what I'm asking is if there is a way to map the Article object attributes so here the attributes product, attribut and parentArticle with only their id and not charge all the Object. I know that Hibernate can help but I would like to set it manually without ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it the ResultSet is actually data you have queried from the database, so any data from this structure is persistent, correct?

What you could do is use [session.load()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) since this will always return a Hibernate proxy, without accessing the database. A Hibernate proxy is an object with only the given identifier, in this case the id, and all other properties have not been initialized yet, it looks like it came from the database but it didn't, it's a synthetic representation of an actual retrieved entity. When acted upon it, if the data it referenced by id should be gone from the persistence layer, the proxy will throws an ObjectNotFoundException.

I know this is probably not what you expected since you've mentioned you're looking for a `ORM-free solution` however I believe this actually serves your purpose of finding a solution for your other expectation, a way to `not charge all the Object` :)

Should you be using JPA the equivalent functionality of Hibernate's session.get() is provided by [EntityManager.html#getReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.